# Docker and file sharing on OS X

Tags: macos, performance, virtual-machine, docker

Ok. I am playing around with different tools to prepare dev environment. Docker is nice option. I created the whole dev environment in docker and can build a project in it.

The source code for this project lives outside of docker container (on the host). This way you can use your IDE to edit it and use docker just to build it.

However, there is one problem

a) Docker on OS X uses VM (VirtualBox VM)

b) File sharing is reasonably slow (way slower than file IO on host)

c) The project has something like a gazzilion files (which exaggerate problems #a an #b).

If I move source code in the docker, I will have the same problem in IDE (it will have to access shared files and it will be slow).

I heard about some workaround to make it fast. However, I can't seem to find any information on this subject.

**Update 1**

I used Docker file sharing feature (meaning I run)

```
docker run -P -i  -v <VMDIR>:<DOCKERDIR> -t <imageName> /bin/bash
```

However, sharing between VM and Docker isn't a problem. It's fast.

The bottle neck is sharing between host and VM.

Comment: By "file sharing" do you mean Virtualbox "shared folders", or a file sharing container exposing, say, SMB, to the Mac?

Comment: I put and update to my question. I use docker -v (which I believe translates to VirtualBox "Shared folders")

Comment: This may help... http://viget.com/extend/how-to-use-docker-on-os-x-the-missing-guide

Comment: That guide is informative to understand what's going on, but it's a bit dated. In particular, `boot2docker` natively supports VirtualBox Extensions now – at least enough to not need it for Shared Folders.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yeah. This is useful guide. However, it doesn't answer the question how to make it faster ;)

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I use is not to use boot2docker but instead have a vagrant VM [provisioned with docker](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/docker.html). No such big penalty for mounting folders host->vagrant->docker.

On the downside, I have to pre-map folders to vagrant (basically my whole work directory) and pre-expose a range of ports from the vagrant box to the host to have access to the docker services directly from there.

On the plus side, when I want to clean unused docker garbage (images, volumes, etc.) I simply destroy the vagrant vm and re-create it again :)

**Elaboration**

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "trusty-docker"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/vagrant/boxes/latest/ubuntu-14.04-amd64-vbox.box"
  config.vm.provision "docker"

  #by default we'll claim ports 9080-9090 on the host system
  for i in 9080..9090
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: i, host: i
  end

  #NB: this folder mapping will not have the boot2docker issue of slow sync
  config.vm.synced_folder "~/work", "/home/vagrant/work"
end
```

Having that:

```
host$ vagrant up && vagrant ssh
vagrant$ docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/work:/work ubuntu:12.04 find /work
```

Comment: Can you explain why it's better? As I understand host->vagrant will still VM folder sharing?

Comment: Provided an example, hope it is clearer. Feel free to ask more questions. Yes, there is still folder sharing, but it is much faster than the boot2docker's one, which AFAIR uses rsync.

Comment: How big is your project? It's still incredible slow for me.

Comment: The biggest problems I saw were javascript (grunt) projects with fs watchers, didn't even have to be that large - around 20K files with dependencies. The approach would make a very big difference. If you don't observe any difference then there is something else or indeed much larger scale than mine.

Comment: Mine is about 40k files. I did what you recommended and run docker inside of vagrant (used your file). However, it's still slow. I added memory to VM. I checked that CPU utilization is low (about 20%). However, it's still way-way slower than building on host. Do you have any suggestion to check what's the bottleneck?

Comment: So you are saying that CPU and RAM don't seem to be an issue and you have much slower building experience than on host. Did you actually try to compare building the files copied to docker container? That is via `ADD` or `COPY` of the Dockerfile, not synchronized with the host. Would it be much faster for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69003/discussion-between-mykola-gurov-and-victor-ronin).

Comment: I did a lot of investigation and still can't see how it's better. boot2docker is essentially = virtual box + docker. vagrant is also equal to virtual box + docker. Copying files in a docker (vs using sharing) helps immensely. Using NFS (vs default virtual box sharing also helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately a typical problem Windows and OS X users are currently struggling with that cannot be solved trivially, especially in the case of Windows users. The main culprit is VirtualBox's `vboxfs` which is used for file sharing which, despite being incredibly useful, results in poor filesystem I/O.

There are numerous situations by which developing the project sources inside the guest VM are brought to a crawl, the main two being scores of 3rd party sources introduce by package managers and Git repositories with a sizable history.

The obvious approach is to move as much of the project-related files outside of `vboxfs` somewhere else into the guest. For instance, symlinking the package manager directory into the project's `vboxfs` tree, with something like:

`mkdir /var/cache/node_modules && ln -s /var/cache/node_modules /myproject/node_modules`

This alone improved the startup time from ~28 seconds down to ~4 seconds for a Node.js application with a few dozen dependencies running on my SSD.

Unfortunately, this is not applicable to managing Git repositories, short of splatting/truncating your history and committing to data loss, unless the Git repository itself is provisioned within the guest, which forces you to have two repositories: one to clone the environment for inflating the guest and another containing the actual sources, where consolidating the two worlds becomes an absolute pain.

The best way to approach the situation is to either:

1. drop `vboxfs` in favor of a shared transport mechanism that results in better I/O in the guest, such as the [Network File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System). Unfortunately, for Windows users, the only way to get NFS service support is to run the enterprise edition of Windows (which I believe will still be true for Windows 10).
2. revert to mounting raw disk partitions into the guest, noting the related risks of giving your hypervisor raw disk access

If your developer audience is wholly compromised of Linux and OS X users, option 1 might be viable. Create a Vagrant machine and configure [NFS shares](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html) between your host and guest and profit. If you do have Windows users, then, short of buying them an enterprise license, it would be best to simply ask them to repartition their disks and work inside a guest VM.

[image: Windows host and Arch Linux guest with raw disk access]

I personally use a Windows host and have a 64 GB partition on my SSD that I mount directly into my Arch Linux guest and operate from there. I also switched to GPT and UEFI and have an option to boot directly into Arch Linux in case I want to circumvent the overhead of the virtualized hardware, giving me the best of both worlds with little compromise.

Comment: I tried NFS. It's much better than VirtualBox default sharing. However, it's still produces huge hit in performance on such big amounf of files. Also, on top of that all writes to the project dir (while build) will be sent back to host (which increases performance hit).

Answer (score 2):

Two steps can improve your performance quite well:

1. **Switch to NFS**. You can [use this script to do this](https://gist.github.com/olalonde/74de9d053448b977f77e).
2. **Switch your VBox NIC driver to `FAST III`.** You can do this on your `default` machine by running:

`VBoxManage modifyvm default --nictype1 Am79C973
VBoxManage modifyvm default --nictype2 Am79C973`

Comment: Very impressive improvement! I have a php project running in docker-machine (boot2docker) was 4s loading time per page. Now it's less than 1s!

Answer (score 1):

I run a simple watch script that kicks off an rsync inside my container(s) from the shared source-code volume to a container-only volume whenever anything changes. My entry-point only reads from the container-only volume so that avoids the performance issues, and rsync works really well, especially if you set it up correctly to avoid things like .git folders and libraries that don't change frequently.

Comment: Just curious. How big is your project?

Comment: BTW. I tried this solution. It works fine. However, it has to go and check timestamps/size for each file in the folder. As result, if only one file has changed it still can take quite a while.

Comment: Interesting. My projects are mostly nodejs packages which we deploy as micro-services so they are not too big. There are a lot of common modules but I have rsync ignore all changes to the node_modules folder so that doesn't slow it down. It's super fast in my experience.

Comment: Sure. If you ignore most of the files (your case) and sync let say 1k files it will be almost instantaneous. It's big monolithic project for me (40k files). I think I can make it smaller by ignoring some files, but it still takes about 30 seconds to handle so many files.

Comment: Yeah, I run a full-transfer whenever I know I need to sync everything, that takes on the order of 30 seconds or so but its pretty rare while I'm usually working.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of pieces of info which I found

- I started to use Vagrant to work with VirtualBox and install Docker in it. It gives more flexibility
- Default sharing in Vagrant VirtualBox provisioning is very slow
- NFS sharing is much faster. However, it could be reasonably slow it (especially if your build process will create files which needs to be written back to this share).
- Vagrant 1.5+ have a rsync option (to use rsync to copy files from host to VM). It's faster because it doesn't have to write back any changes.
- This rsync option has autosync (to continiously sync it).
- This rsync option consumes a lot of CPU and people came up with a gem to overcome it (https://github.com/smerrill/vagrant-gatling-rsync)

So, Vagrant + VirtualBox + Rsync shared folder + auto rsync + vagrant gatling looks like a good option for my case (still researching it).

I tried vagrant gatling. However, it results in non deterministic behavior. I never know whether new files were copied into VM or not. It wouldn't be a problem if it would take 1 second. However, it make take 20 seconds which is too much (a user can switch a window and start build when new files weren't synced yet).

Now, I am thinking about some way to copy over ONLY files which changed. I am still in research phase.The idea would be to use FSEvent to listen for file changes and send over only changed files. It looks like there are some tools around which do that.

BTW. Gatling internally using FSEvent. The only problem that it triggers full rsync (which goes and start comparing date/times and sizes for 40k files)

Comment: One more additional thought. Both Rsync auto and Gatling try to synchronize whole folder. I feel like there could be a solution which try to synchronize modified files only.